# What's the value of the coupling constant in interacting field theories?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

Consider this Lagrangian :

$L = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \Phi)^2 - \frac{M^2}{2}\Phi^2 +\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \phi)^2 -\frac{m^2}{2} \phi^2 -\mu\Phi\phi^2$

Its interaction term is given by : $\int d^3x \space\mu\Phi\phi^2$

When $M>2m$ a $\Phi$ particle can decay in 2 $\phi$ particle, this process is called "Scalar Particle Decay".

My question is, what's the value of the coupling constant $\mu$ in this process?

Thank you!

Comment: Um...$\mu$ takes the value you choose it to take. The coupling constants must always be determined experimentally at some scale during the process of renormalization, anyway, and so I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Tank you for your response... But, for example, in an exercise For example, one exercise asks me to calculate the lifetime of $\Phi$ to lowest order in $\mu$. Solving it, I get the final result : $\tau = frac{8\pi M}{\mu^2}(1-4\sqrt(\frac{m^2}{M^2})$ ... So without knowing the value of $\mu$, I can not calculate numerically the formula, right?

Comment: Then you calculate it to lowest order in $\mu$. You don't need to know the value of $\mu$ for that, it'll just stay there as a parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the last response

Comment: Yup, you're right, you can't get a numerical value. I do not think that anyone would *expect* a numerical value from the information given, so that's quite alright.